# Python pandas: get unique id from column 1 if "string" not contains on column 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
BillID    |         A           | B
-------------------------------------
bill-1    | Pharmacy Medicine   | IP
bill-1    | Pharmacy sale       | IP
bill-1    |  Doctors            | IP
bill-2    |  Pharmacy sale      | IP
bill-2    |  Pharmacy Medicine  | IP 
bill-3    |  Pharmacy sale      | IP
bill-4    | Hospitals           | IP
```

I want to print only rows where the column "A" contains only "pharmacy" values. if the BillID contains anything other than "pharmacy" and I want to ignore that.
due to **bill-1** has "Doctors" also on column "B" I don't want "bill-1" value.

The example output I am looking for is this:

```
BillID |              A          | B      
------------------------------------------ 
bill-2    |  Pharmacy sale       | IP      
bill-2    |  Pharmacy Medicine   | IP    
bill-3    |  Pharmacy sale       | IP
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas quickly and without using a loop? Thanks

Comment: Are you about your columns labels ?

Comment: @tgrandje, sorry, I am not getting what you are asking

Comment: You have just edited your question, it makes much more sense !

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a bit more clarity on what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood what you wanted :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
def check_pharmacy(df):
  pharmacy_everywhere = all(df['A'].str.contains('Pharmacy'))
  return pharmacy_everywhere
d = df.groupby('BillID').apply(check_pharmacy).to_dict()
print(df[df.BillID.map(d)])
```

Some explanations:
[df.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) allows you group by BillID. If you use the *apply* method, then the function takes the subdataframe (grouped on this value) as an argument.
If you wan to see what happens, you can use df.groupby(...).apply(print)

The check_pharmacy then checks if 'A' contains Pharmacy on each rows and returns True if that is the case for all rows. False if that is not the case. As a result, you get a DataFrame of 2 columns : BillID and the result of check_pharmacy. Converting it to dict allows you to use this as mapping argument on the original BillID column for Boolean Indexing, and you're through.

Is this what you were searching for ?

Comment: hey this is what exactly I was looking for. thank man.